# Should there be a "20th century Christianity" or "Modern Christianity" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

It seems to me a 20th-century-Christianity tag or modern-Christianity tag would be useful to distinguish between questions like [this one](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/30398/what-connection-jesus-movement-and-pentecostal-charismatic-movement-do-have-if-a), which asks about the Jesus Movement and the Pentecostalism Movement, and questions about for example, Church councils, schisms, and the practices of churches throughout history.

Answer (score 7):

meh - I think the existing tags got the job done for that one.  And applying "church history" to modern church history is entirely legit in my view.  There are actually tags already for ecumenical-council and schism believe it or not.